# Sony UP-DR150 printer setup confussion on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-11, printer, printing

I'm at my wit's end after spending days trying to get my Sony UP-DR150 photo printer up and running. Despite the seller's assurances that it works flawlessly on both Windows 10 and 11 (even providing test prints as proof), I'm stuck in a loop of frustration, unable to replicate their success.

The crux of the problem lies in the driver availability; the only one I could unearth is meant for Windows XP 32-bit, and it outright refuses to install on my 64-bit machine. I stumbled upon a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgduA7YgoAU) suggesting a workaround with a driver for a different model (UPD711MD), which is actually intended for medical printers. Miraculously, it allowed me to establish a connection with the printer. However, the driver doesn't support color printing and consistently doesn’t have the right paper sizes. Maybe I could edit the INF file?

At this point, it feels like I'm chasing a phantom solution. Has anyone else faced this daunting challenge and emerged victorious? Any guidance or pointers towards finding the correct driver for the Sony UP-DR150 that's compatible with newer Windows versions would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting -  https://almalinux.pkgs.org/8/almalinux-appstream-x86_64/gutenprint-cups-5.2.14-3.el8.x86_64.rpm.html - implies that this printer uses Postscript - which is a generic printing language.  If this is correct you can most likely use the Microsoft generic Postscript Printer driver (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/microsoft-postscript-printer-driver)  or maybe a driver for another Postscript printer - you will need to tweek sizes etc though.

Comment: I can’t see where to download the drivers from this page. Any idea? Many thanks

Comment: I dont use Windows anymore, but generic drivers are included with Windows.  You may need to search for the printer manually.  I

Answer (score 0):

I found a [website](https://productz.com/en/sony-up-dr150/p/VDrP6) that claims the printer supports normal image formats like BNP, JPG, GIF, PNG and TIP. If that is correct, the following solution may be possible - on condition that you can set up a USB connection to the printer. If the PC sees the printer on the USB, you can install it as a local printer. Use any driver you like, e.g. the Generic/Text Only driver.

If that works, try the following.

First share the printer, even if you are the only user. Then set up a virtual LPT1 port, with the command

NET USE LPT1: \computername\printer_sharename /persistent:yes

Finally try COPYing an image to the port, with

COPY /B filename LPT1:

Comment: Is it possible to automate this process? I’m trying to set up photo booth software which prints automatically to a pre-configured printer

Comment: It may be possible using software that can send keystrokes, such as AutoHotkey or Powershell Send-KeyStrokes. However, you first need to test whether it can print images directly.

Answer (score -1):

If you download a driver from third-party driver sites, such as
[driverscape](https://www.driverscape.com/download/sony-up-dr150),
the driver dates from 2008, so certainly cannot work on Windows 10.

You have no choice but to use the Windows generic driver.

If the generic driver doesn't work, and you absolutely wish to use
this printer, create a 32-bit virtual machine with Windows XP where
you can install your driver.

Alternatively, you could try the
[OpenPrinting project](https://openprinting.github.io/)
whose main purpose is to enable using legacy printers that are
no longer supported in Linux.

Follow the article
[OpenPrinting keeps old printers working – even on Windows](https://www.theregister.com/2022/11/10/openprinting_keeps_old_printers_working/) :

> In brief, how it works is this: you install WSL from the Microsoft Store, then install Ubuntu in it. You add the Printer Application "snap" (the term for a bundle of an app and its dependencies) and the snap with drivers for your old-but-still-functional printer, then point Windows at the WSL VM's IP address. Presto – you can add, and then print to, a printer to which Windows itself can no longer talk.

Comment: Is it possible to give more detailed instructions on how to do this? I tried to follow this tutorial (https://openprinting.github.io/wsl-printer-app/) but ran into a bunch or errors on Ubuntu and couldn’t add the Sony printer. Also, what do you mean by generic printer drivers? Where can I download them? Thanks!

Comment: I was referring to whatever drivers Windows decided to attach to the printer, if it's truly detected as a printer. I don't have experience with that project.